# Blank Space at the bottom when using SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I want to implement the SingleScrollView to avoid the bottom overflow problem that appears whenever I use the keyboard on the form fields. However when I add the widget I get a blank space on the bottom and I don't really know how to solve it.

I have actively searched for a solution but I am a noob.

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
bool loading = false;
GlobalKey<FormState> loginKeyForm = new GlobalKey();
TextEditingController emailCtrl = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController passwordCtrl = new TextEditingController();
String _error;
double screenHeight;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(80, 255, 162, 1),
              Color.fromRGBO(199, 250, 240, 1),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
              _topLogo(),
              SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.02),
              _loginForm(),
              SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.02),
              _socialLogins(),
              SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.06),
              _newAcountButton(),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: loading ? LoadingWidget() : Container(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F549y.png)

Comment: Give height to container (before SingleChildScrollView)  it might be help you.

Comment: Yeah, that worked, thanks!